# JSON is not being recognised

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Im having a bit of trouble getting my JSON to be recognised by my web page. I have validated JSON that im getting returned from server, so i know that is correct, however my javascript function is not doing anything with it. My succes function is as follows:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('input[name=customer_name]').val(data.name);
  $('textarea[name=customer_address]').text(data.address);
  $('input[name=customer_email]').val(data.email);
  $('input[name=customer_tel]').val(data.tel);
  $('input[name=user_id]').val(item.id);
}
```

Yet the fields are not being repopulated with the data that is returned, if it helps, a sample of my JSON data:

```
{
    "name": "Terry O'Toole",
    "address": "Terrys House\nTerry Street\nTerrysville\nTerrytown\nTT1 6TT",
    "email": "teryy@two.com",
    "tel": "05110000000"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[EDIT]

Expanded ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo site_url('user/users/ajax'); ?>",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {"userid": item.id},
  success: function(data) {
    $('input[name=customer_name]').val(data.name);
    $('textarea[name=customer_address]').text(data.address);
    $('input[name=customer_email]').val(data.email);
    $('input[name=customer_tel]').val(data.tel);
    $('input[name=user_id]').val(item.id);
  }
 })
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code, because nothing looks wrong with what you've posted. What does your ajax call look like?

Comment: Added the expanded ajax.

Comment: `<?php ... ?>` indicates PHP code. That's irrelevant to JavaScript: you need to look at the *generated* source code. Also, are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it you're using jQuery (from the `val` function you're using). Are you specifying the `dataType` parameter to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "blah",
    dataType: "json",
    success: ...
});
```

If not, it may not be guessing correctly (perhaps you're not sending back the right content type?) and you'll have to use `JSON.parse` on it. But best to A) Set the correct content type on the response, and B) use `dataType` to express your intent in the code.

**Edit** Just saw your edit. Definitely try adding `dataType`.

Comment: Ha got it. Adding the datatype worked a treat. Thanks for the help

Comment: @richzila: If this answer worked for you, tick it as accepted.

Comment: @richzila: No worries, glad that was it.